how can i modify my code so it can be repetitively executed to compute n! for different n’s
.globl __start

.rodata
msg1: .string "Enter a number (or negative number to quit): "
msg2: .string "The factorial of "
msg3: .string " is: "
msg4: .string "\nDo you want to calculate another factorial (y/n)? "

.text

__start:

loop:
    # Print prompt for user input
    li a0, 4      # syscall for write string
    la a1, msg1
    ecall

    # Get user input
    li a0, 5      # syscall for read integer
    ecall
    mv x10, a0    # move input to register x10 (n)

    # Check if negative (n < 0)
    blt x10, x0, exit  # branch less than (negative) to exit

    # Print message "The factorial of "
    li a0, 4      # syscall for write string
    la a1, msg2
    ecall

    # Print the number before calculating factorial
    li a0, 1      # syscall for write integer
    mv a1, x10    # move n to print register
    ecall

    # Recursive call: fact(n)
    mv a0, x10   # Move n to a0 for recursive call
    jal ra, fact # call fact function with n

    # Print message " is: "
    li a0, 4     # syscall for write string
    la a1, msg3
    ecall

    # Print the result (factorial)
    li a0, 1     # syscall for write integer
    mv a1, a0    # move result to print register
    ecall

    # Jump back to the beginning of the loop for another calculation
    j loop

exit:
    # Exit program
    li a0, 10
    ecall

fact:  # recursive function for factorial
    # Save return address (ra) and the argument (n) onto the stack
    addi sp, sp, -16
    SW ra, 12(sp)  # Save return address
    SW a0, 8(sp)   # Save argument (n)

    # Base case: if n = 0 or n = 1, return 1
    beqz a0, end_fact
    li t0, 1
    beq a0, t0, end_fact

    # Recursive case: fact(n-1)
    addi a0, a0, -1  # Decrement n
    jal ra, fact     # Recursive call
    lw t1, 8(sp)     # Restore n
    mul a0, a0, a1   # Multiply result by n
    ret

end_fact:
    # Return 1 for the base case (factorial of 0 or 1)
    li a0, 1
    ret


I want to make the code to repetitively executed to compute n! for different n’s. But when I type any number, it just still calculate the factorial of 1
I have tried to modify the code so that after the recursive call to fact(n-1), the result is moved back to x10 register for proper storage and later printing, and then after the recursive call to fact(n-1), the result is stored in register a1 and then multiplied by n before returning

Please tag the processor and/or the instruction set you are using, as well as the assembler, a valid set should be like this: ([assembly] [x86] [gnu-assembler] or [att]).

li a0, 1; mv a1, a0 will of course always print 1.
